# German equivalent for the verb “trigger” meaning to cause something to happen?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

The phrase I am trying to translate is for a project with an internet powered device to do its programmed purpose. For example, A pressing the button will cause a light source to illuminate or a sprinkler to begin dispersing water.

I need to translate the phrase which will be a label on a button

> Trigger Device

I found one translation in a dictionary for trigger *auslösen*, but I think perhaps *starten* may be a better equivalent for the verb of trigger in English which means that it causes something. My concern is that there is another use for the word "trigger" which means a part of a firearm.

My concern would be with the grammar of the entire phrase, I do not want to have something like device trigger which would describe a component on a device.

Comment: Where do you think the verb comes from? I guess from the trigger of a gun.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis That's unlikely. Trigger should go back to some germanic origin where also the german word *drücken* comes from.

Comment: @Javatasse: The noun *trigger* probably goes back to the Dutch word *trekker*, from the Dutch verb *trekken* (to pull). And the verb *to trigger* is very likely derived from the noun (originally meaning *pulling the trigger*). So, not unlikely at all. And not *drücken* but the opposite: *trekken* = *ziehen*.

Comment: If you really mean "push (or click) this to trigger the device" or similar, then perhaps "Gerät aktivieren" would be a possible caption, or just "Aktivieren". And even in English, I don't think I would use "trigger device".

Comment: You are concerned about the entire phrase, you say. In this case it might be a good idea to quote the entire phrase. This will help us give you good solutions. Selection of words and expressions depends to large extent on the proper context.

Comment: it is [seemingly common](http://context.reverso.net/%C3%BCbersetzung/englisch-deutsch/the+trigger+device) to use the word `Triggereinrichtung` in technical contexts as yours. There even is a [German patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/DE102006039395A1/de) and a [proper Duden entry](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Trigger) for "Trigger".

Comment: Please clarify your quoted phrase: is trigger a verb in there, as in “[to] trigger [the] device”, or is it a noun as in “[the] trigger[ing] device”? Since you keep asking about verbs, I assume the former, but just reading the quote at first I would have assumed the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a technical context like yours, it is perfectly fine to use the translation

> Triggereinrichtung

"Trigger" is a [noun](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Trigger),
increasingly [appearing in texts](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Trigger) since the year 2000 to be understood,
and there is a history of using the compound "Triggereinrichtung" in [patents](https://patents.google.com/patent/DE102006039395A1/de) and [other sources](http://context.reverso.net/%C3%BCbersetzung/englisch-deutsch/the+trigger+device).

**After your last edit**, what I wrote above is still true but it does not apply to the question any more. To label a button "Trigger Device" is ambiguous even in English. Consider asking this on the [UX stack](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) to get some expert suggestions for that.

I would go with *Starten*, *Einschalten* or *Aktivieren*, then. The last one is the least specific. *Energie!* only if your users are nerds.

*Auslösen* is not the verb associated with switching on a light source or turning on the sprinkler you mentioned in your examples. I would expect something more spectacular to happen on *Auslösen* (or a shipment from the online pawn shop, as @janka has so humorously remarked earlier).

Comment: This was the best fit from what I saw when researching the word and it's recent use in electrical engineering.

Comment: I don't control the copy, i am just trying to translate from what already exists.

Comment: "triggern" has likely been a common loan word amongst oscilloscope users for decades :) Every attempt to use a classic german word for it would only cause confusion.

Comment: "*Triggereinrichtung*" autsch!

Comment: the first part of this answer is now obsolete. it had been accepted before OP added their context, which asks for something quite different. I do not have sufficient rep here on this stack to delete it as long as it is accepted.

Answer (score 20):

The problem is not so much the *trigger* part, but the *device* part. You cannot trigger an arbitrary thing in German, and I wonder if you should be able to do it in English either. You can trigger a **function** however.

> Eingestellte Funktion auslösen

*Trigger selected function*

That's what I recommend. An example in a sentence:

> Küchendunst löste den Fehlalarm aus.

*Kitchen haze triggered the false alarm.*

It's a bit of a grey area sometimes:

> Da hat die Falle ausgelöst.

*Then the trap was triggered.*

I think *starten* is a really poor translation, because it could mean anything. Most people would think is power-ups the device or reboots it.

---

Triggering a gun is *abfeuern* in German, and the trigger is called *der Abzug*. No connection to *auslösen*.

Comment: All good points. With that said, would it make sense to perhaps say `Gerät einleiten` to "Initiate Device" as opposed to triggering a device, since really we would be triggering an action?

Comment: AFAICT, "trigger device" does not mean "triggering a device", it means "a device that triggers". Cf. https://www.linguee.de/englisch-deutsch/uebersetzung/trigger+device.html and I would call it "Auslösevorrichtung".

Comment: @JGallardo No, *Gerät einleiten* doesn't work in german. To initiate a device in the sense of prepare is *vorbereiten*, to initiate in the sense of reset it would be *zurücksetzen*.

Comment: *Einleiten* has the same problem as *auslösen*. It's needs an action or at least an item which is commonly connected with a specific action. *Gerät* is completely unspecific. What should *Gerät auslösen* or *Gerät einleiten* mean? **I** would think one of the other meanings of the verbs matched – *get the device back from a pawn shop* for *Gerät auslösen* and *flush the device down the sewage* for *Gerät einleiten*.

Comment: I agree with all that you mentioned, i forgot to mention however that I am using it as a label on a button, so I needed something shorter for my use case.

Comment: It's *Funktion auslösen* or *Auslösen* then.

Comment: Shame this isn't the accepted answer.

Comment: Einen Schuss auslösen ...

Answer (score 19):

The verb connected to this is indeed *auslösen*. Hence, how about *Auslöser* for the device?

Comment: This is the only correct answer, feel free to remove the question mark.

Comment: Ich verstehe die Frage so, dass der Trigger ein Device auslöst, nicht, dass der Trigger das Device ist.

Answer (score 9):

It seems you are looking for a noun (like trigger device). Without knowing the proper context it is not possible to give a good solution. Here are some words that may or may not fit, depending on context

- Auslöseeinrichtung
- Startvorrichtung (somehow evokes the image of a motor or engine being started... but could be used also for other appliances)
- Einschaltvorrichtung (to start an electrical device; could fit for your application)
- Trigger (sometimes used in informal speech not least due to the word being short)
- Abzug (only with guns)
- Auslöser (can be used in variuos mechanical devices)
- Schalter (not least in software)
- Signalgeber (where action is not mechanical but rather based on a signal, usually in form of electricity)
- Geber (as above; the term will usually be used only by engineers, not in everyday life; by the way, a *Geber* could also be strictly mechanical, e.g. measuring the water gauge somewhere and then triggering some action of a device)

It really depends on the specific device you want to address...

Comment: I have a question on "Auslöseeinrichtung" I think that describes the device does it not? a triggering device?

Answer (score 3):

Several options. The most literal translation to "trigger device" would be

> Gerät auslösen

Since you want to be fairly unspecific about what the device will do, once "triggered" you could also use

> Gerät triggern

For once "Jemanden triggern" is somewhat common with a lot of younger people in Germany - and even in English you are using the word as an abstract placeholder for "The device will do something" - so an abstract word with minimal connotation will probably fit best.

Comment: Yes I originally went with the literal translation, but I like how "Gerät triggern" can be used more generally.

Comment: @JGallardo in general, German tends to be less general and more specific, therefore one cannot tell which term would suit best, unless knowing the type of device, which is being triggered. or how would you translate "to pull the trigger on someone" (which cannot be literally translated)? it might not even be certain, if we would call it a "trigger device".

Answer (score 3):

would call it `Auslösevorrichtung` / `Auslöseeinrichtung` ...

or simply `Auslöser` - or even literally `Auslösegerät` or an `Impulsgeber`.

Answer (score 1):

In the IT sphere we often use the word

> anstoßen

for actions, that have to be triggered and that will go on for a while.

Comment: However, most everyone in IT and EE will find "triggern" a pretty normal word.

Comment: @rackandboneman: Yes, this is also true. We also say "antriggern".

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to avoid *auslösen* at any cost, I'd translate

> Trigger Device

as

> Startknopf

Answer (score 1):

I'd say Auslöser, which was the designation for a button on older Photocameras for example. Gun Triggers are called "Abzug", but this word rather refers to the act of pulling. Auslösen is more like dispatching something like a signal or triggering a mechanism, causing an event to happen. Startknopf is just a composite word of start and button. Simply, if you do not wanna use start button, do not use Startknopf. :-)

Answer (score -2):

It is

> Ein Gerät auslösen

or if you want to mean "trigger an event" it would be

> Ein Ereignis auslösen.

Comment: Yes, "trigger" means "auslösen", but "Ein Gerät auslösen" is not correct usage.